# Disable link from being click on Internet explorer 10

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, href, internet-explorer-10

Hey guys I am trying to disable a link from being clicked. I tried using a CSS solution:

```
.link-disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

It doesn't work in IE10 and below. Is there a CSS or jQuery solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.link-disabled').click(function(){return false;});
```

Explanation:

`return false;` in an event handler prevents the default action and stops the event propagation through the DOM.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xv6zaanf/1/)

Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: Yes @RoryMcCrossan: this will disable on all browsers but that's  what SrMissAlot wanted. Indeed she said: 'i went on css solution : but in don't work in IE10 and below'...

Comment: @SrMissAlot: I updated the answer with a fiddle, please check it ;)

Comment: Note: This solution doesn't handle the situation where the user accesses the link using the Context Menu or the scroll button!